# Is it necessary to close the file in json.load?

Tags: python, json, file

It's clear that a file object should be closed to delete it from memory:

```
file = open('data.txt', 'r')
#more code here
file.close()
```

Is it also necessary to close a file object served to the `json.load` method?

```
data = json.load(open('data.json','r'))
```

I guess no since the file object not stored in a variable, but if yes, how can it be done?

Comment: Unfortunately the second part of your question was never answered, and I am also wondering how it can be done, if it even can at all.

Answer (score 14):

Don't rely on the GC to clean/close the file descriptor.
Use a [context manager](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/#specification-the-with-statement) instead.

You also don't need to provide the mode `'r'` since it is the default for `open`.

```
with open('data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Comment: `Don't rely on the GC to clean/close the file descriptor`
Are you saying that the GC never closes the file or that it is not sure whether it will close it or not.

Comment: @multigoodverse I'm saying that you can't rely on the GC to close the file when you expect that it would.

Answer (score 0):

For me closing a json file works like normal file handling in python.

filename.close()

Comment: This does does not answer the question asked by OP *Is it* ***necessary*** *to close the file in json.load?*